# Add item to Right click Drag and Drop contextual menu on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, registry, regedit

I need to add items to the contextual menu when I drag and drop a file using the right click.

I can manage to add item in registry for just right click on the file, but not when dragging to another folde.

This is what I'm using just for the right click and works fine.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\TrimResizePicture]
@="Players/Pictures Trim Resize to *x1500"
"Icon"="C:\\cmd_Scripts\\photo2.ico,0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\TrimResizePicture\command]
@="\"C:\\cmd_Scripts\\resize_trim_picture.bat\" \"%1\""
```

This is what I've tried for drag and drop right click, and is not working.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\DragDropHandlers\TrimResizePicture]
@="Players/Pictures Trim Resize to *x1500"
"Icon"="C:\\cmd_Scripts\\photo2.ico,0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\DragDropHandlers\TrimResizePicture\command]
@="\"C:\\cmd_Scripts\\resize_trim_picture.bat\" \"%1\""
```

This is the menu I need to add stuff

[image: This is the menu I need to add stuff]